# When Does a $C^*$-algebra have a Subalgebra Invariant under Involution?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I know very little about $C^*$-algebras but am intrigued by this question. In the trivial case of the complex field itself, the reals are such a subalgebra. Are there any other cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider for example $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be self-adjoint. Then the set

$$ \{ p(A) \, | \, p \in \mathbb{R}[X] \} $$

which consists of the matrices that are real polynomials in $A$ is a real algebra invariant under conjugation. For example if $A = \operatorname{diag}(1,1,2)$ then this algebra is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Note that your example doesn't really use matrices. You can do it in any C$^*$-algebra. And you can take any real algebra of continuous functions, instead of real polynomials.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Yeah, I just didn't want to think about whether in general I should take the closure or not and give a concrete (although trivial) example.

Comment: @MartinArgerami. I thought of any algebra generated by a Hermitian subset of $C^*(x)$ immediately after posting. Still though, is there any theoretical result which guarantees the set of Hermitian operators is nonempty under various circumstances?

Comment: Yes, any C$^*$-algebra is the linear span of its selfadjoint elements. Actually, any element is of the form $a+ib $, with $a,b $ selfadjoint.

Answer (score 2):

When $A$ is abelian, the selfadjoint elements form a real algebra. So, for an arbitrary C$^*$-algebra $A$, take $x\in A$ selfadjoint, and then $C^*(x)$ is an abelian C$^*$-algebra and its selfadjoint elements (which amount to $f(x)$ for $f$ continuous, as in Levap's answer) gives a real subalgebra invariant under the involution.